# Convert entire string into integer and display it in textfield swift

Tags: swift, types

I want to develop an application that can convert `UITextField` values into integer, float and double.
I am facing problem to convert `String` value into `Integer`.
Can anyone suggest the better way for conversion.
I have tried the following code but it didn't worked for `Swift 4` and `Xcode 10.`

```
let result = txtTotakeInput.text    
var newSTrings = Int(result!)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add ! . see my code var newSTrings = Int(result!)! . you have to enter only numeric value into textfield.

Comment: Got your point!Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and safer way to handle all three types `Int`, `Float` and `Double` will be

```
let result = txtTotakeInput.text   
if let intVal = Int(result ?? "") {
    // Use interger
}
else if let floatVal = Float(result ?? "") {
    // Use float
}
else if let doubleVal = Double(result ?? "") {
    // Use double
}
else {
    print("User has not entered integer, float or double")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Int.init(_ string)` returns an optional, since its possible that the string is not an integer.  So you can either make newStrings optional like `var newSTrings = result.flatMap(Int.init)` or nil coalesce it to zero or some other default `var newSTrings = result.flatMap(Int.init) ?? 0`